# Example of building Bokeh panels with complex layouts?

Tags: python, bokeh

I am trying to make Bokeh Panels that have relatively complex layouts, so I tried moving half of my current layout into one `Panel` and half into another just to play around, like so:

```
selects = HBox(top_users_select, new_users_select, t1_users_select, t2_users_select, top_recent_users_select)
tab1 = Panel(inputs)
tab2 = Panel(VBox(HBox(plot2, plot1, plot3, plot4), HBox(plot5, plot6, plot7, plot8), data_table))
tabs = tabs(tab1, tab2)
show(tabs)
```

However this is giving me the following error:

```
File "main_panel.py", line 589, in <module>:
tab1 = Panel(inputs) Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/joe/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bokeh/application/handlers/code_runner.py", line 71, in run
    exec(self._code, module.__dict__)
  File "/Users/joe/Desktop/scripts/src/main/python/Bokeh apps/insights/main_panel.py", line 589, in <module>
    tab1 = Panel(inputs)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I am fairly new to Bokeh, and looking at the docs I don't know exactly how to parse this error and get around it. **Can someone point me to an example of laying out fairly complex grids in a Bokeh panel or tell me what the error means and how I can address it?**

Answer (score 2):

You can use `row` or `column` to create complex layouts within tabs.
You can even mix them like `row(column(button1, button2), button3)`

**Example**:

```
from bokeh.models.widgets import Panel, Tabs, Toggle, TextInput
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show
from bokeh.plotting import figure

from bokeh.layouts import column, row  

p1 = figure(plot_width=300, plot_height=300)
p1.circle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 2, 4, 5], size=20, color="navy", alpha=0.5)

p2 = figure(plot_width=300, plot_height=300)
p2.line([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 2, 4, 5], line_width=3, color="navy", alpha=0.5)

toggle1 = Toggle(label="Foo", button_type="success")
toggle2 = Toggle(label="Foo", button_type="warning")
text_input = TextInput(value="default", title="Label:")

tab1 = Panel(child=row(p1,toggle2), title="circle")
tab2 = Panel(child=column(p2,toggle1, text_input), title="line")

tabs = Tabs(tabs=[ tab1, tab2 ])
output_notebook()
show(tabs)
```

See https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/layout.html for more details

Comment: This example gives an error. In `tab2 = Panel(child=column(p2,toggle, text_input), title="line")`, `toggle` isn't defined. I suppose you meant `toggle1`, in which case the example can be run correctly

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to write `selects` instead of `inputs`, but there are basically some things wrong with your declaration.

Look at the examples at http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/widgets.html#tabs

```
from bokeh.models.widgets import Panel, Tabs
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.plotting import figure

output_file("slider.html")

p1 = figure(plot_width=300, plot_height=300)
p1.circle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 2, 4, 5], size=20, color="navy", alpha=0.5)
tab1 = Panel(child=p1, title="circle")

p2 = figure(plot_width=300, plot_height=300)
p2.line([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 2, 4, 5], line_width=3, color="navy", alpha=0.5)
tab2 = Panel(child=p2, title="line")

tabs = Tabs(tabs=[ tab1, tab2 ])

show(tabs)
```

Your input in Panel should be assigned to `child=` and a Panel needs a `title=`.

Also change

```
 tabs = tabs(tab1, tab2)
```

to

```
tabs = Tabs(tabs=[tab1,tab2,tab3,tab4])
```